# Trouble syncing folders in Terminal due to permissions

Tags: terminal, command-line

I've set up a virtual server and am trying to sync files from my local machine to it. I keep getting permissions errors, and am not really sure where to start.

When I attempt this: `rsync -avz htdocs [username]@[virtual-server-domain]:/mnt/`

This is the error I get:

```
    [user]@[computername] ~ % rsync -avz htdocs [username]@[virtual-server-domain]:/mnt/
htdocs?\240[user]@[domain]: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/2288acc43c/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-55/rsync/io.c(453) [receiver=2.6.9]
[user]@[computername] ~ %
```

I checked the permissions on the folder I'm trying to sync to, and it shows:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel      512 Sep 19 00:13 mnt
```

Any ideas as to what I need to change without leaving security vulnerabilities? I've tried while SSH'd into the virtual server as super user, and just on my standard (not-ssh-d in) command line, and neither seems to work. Thank you!